# Passing arguments with curl with json header / passing arguments separated with ? in NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I want to like pass the arguments in insert into in a curl with "?" between them.
this code like works like this localhost:8000/api/addBrand
localhost:8000/api/deleteBrand/3 for example
but like what i want is this for example localhost:8000/api/addBrand?something?something?something?something?
is this possible ? or is there other methods to pass arguments in http or in curl cause mostly i'll work with curl . Thank you

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mariadb = require('mariadb/callback');

    const db = mariadb.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'root',
     database: 'nodemysql'
    });

     db.connect((err) => {
     if(err){
            throw err;
        }
     else{
        console.log('MariaDB Connected...');
     }
     });

     const app = express();
     // Create DB
    app.get('/api/createdb', (req, res) => {
        let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE nodemysql';
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            res.send('Database created...');
        });
    });

    // Create table
    app.get('/api/createBrand', (req, res) => {
        let sql = 'CREATE TABLE Brand(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(50), description VARCHAR(255), country VARCHAR(50), websiteurl VARCHAR(100), livestream VARCHAR(150), PRIMARY KEY(id))';
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            res.send('Brand table created...');
        });
    });

    // Insert brand
    app.get('/api/addBrand', (req, res) => {

        let sql = 'INSERT into Brand(title, description, country, websiteurl, livestream)  values("something", "something", "something", "something.ma", "something.ma/something")';
        let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            res.send('Brand added...');
        });
    });

// Delete Brand
app.get('/api/deleteBrand/:id', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `DELETE FROM Brand WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Brand deleted...');
    });
});
app.listen('8000', () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 8000');
});
```

Comment: [That's not valid syntax for a URL query string.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) Additionally, your `DELETE` statement has an [SQL injection vulnerability](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection)

Comment: thank you , can you please tell me what should i do cause i'm overwhelmed

Comment: @CherryDT should this be like this   : let sql = `DELETE FROM Brand WHERE id = ' + connection.escape(req.params.id)  +';